# basic config to run a python docker image via AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda

I have five hours trying to get a Lambda function to successfully return a response, using a Docker image, and failing miserably.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9.6-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
CMD ["python", "/app/lambda_handler.py"]
```

Python files
p.py

```
def c(a1, a1, a1):
    result = {
        "a1": a1,
        "a2": a2,
        "a3": a3,
    }
    return result
```

lambda_handler.py

```
import json
from p import c
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    arg1 = event["a1"]
    arg2 = event["a2"]
    arg3 = event["a3"]

    result = classify(arg1, arg2, arg3)

    response = {"statusCode": 200, "body": result}

    return json.dumps(response, indent=4, default=str)
```

I get an unhelpful error of

> {
> "errorType": "Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint",
> "errorMessage": "RequestId: 330fa2c3-f68b-4225-a53c-96f2409f186d Error: exec: "lambda_function.lambda_handler": executable file not found in $PATH"
> }

I have tried:

- zipping the files and uploading to the lambda function which works
- read [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html) which suggests using using something like CMD [ "lambda_function.handler" ] so I have set the override CMD to combinations of app.lambda_function.lambda_handler, lambda_function.lambda_handler with and without quotes
- I have tried setting the ENTRYPOINT to python, and then trying to point the CMD to /app/lambda_handler
- instead of using CMD exclusively using ENTRYPOINT override `python, /app/lambda_handler.py`

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears to be a configuration problem with your AWS Lambda function.

If you check the message it says `Error type: Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint ... Error: exec: "lambda_function.lambda_handler"`

By default the Entrypoint of AWS Lambda in the console is `lambda_function.lambda_handler` and [according to the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html) this is

> .. This function handler name reflects the function name (`lambda_handler`) and the file where the handler code is stored (`lambda_function.py`).

In your case your python file is named `lambda_handler.py` instead of `lambda_function.py` which is why AWS Lambda fails to find your handler and throws the error InvalidEntrypoint.

Try changing the name of your file to `lambda_function.py`